# How to reset effect in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I started the main window (class `Main`) and the modal window (class `Login`) with login and password. While actively modal window, main stage =

```
root.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());
```

If user is valid modal window is closed. How to reset the effect in main stage

```
root.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());?
```

Thanks!
Main class:

public class Main extends Application {

```
Login loginWindow = new Login();

public static Stage windowMain;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/main.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/style/main.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    windowMain = primaryStage;
    root.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());
    loginWindow.display();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Login class:

public class Login {

```
public void display() throws IOException {
    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    auth.setTranslateY(40);
    auth.setTranslateX(100);
    auth.getStyleClass().add("auth");
    TextField username = new TextField();
    username.setTranslateY(70);
    username.setTranslateX(75);
    PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
    password.setTranslateY(100);
    password.setTranslateX(75);
    Button loginBtn = new Button();
    loginBtn.getStyleClass().add("loginBtn");
    loginBtn.setStyle("-fx-cursor: hand");
    loginBtn.setTranslateX(115);
    loginBtn.setTranslateY(155);

    loginBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (username.getText().equals("admin") && password.getText().equals("admin")) {
                window.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    });

    Pane layout = new Pane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(username, password, loginBtn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    layout.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/style/login.css").toExternalForm());

    username.setFocusTraversable(false);
    password.setFocusTraversable(false);

    window.setScene(scene);
    window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    window.showAndWait();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default value for `effect` is null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#effectProperty), so

```
root.setEffect(null);
```

should work. Since you use `showAndWait()` in the login window, all you need is

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/main.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/style/main.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    windowMain = primaryStage;
    root.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());
    loginWindow.display();
    root.setEffect(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I get scene from Main class?

Comment: Please don't place code in comments, instead edit the question and add formatted code to the question.

Comment: James_D, Thanks a lot!!